# Distribute elements evenly (adding ints values to array of int values)

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of Ints and all elements equal zero. It'd look something like this:

```
let arr: [Int] =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There are 11 elements in this array in total. I want three of the elements in this array to be the number one. I want these one values to be distributed evenly throughout the array so that it looks something like this:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I want to be able to add however many one's and distribute them evenly (or as close to evenly as possible) no matter how many total elements there are. How could I do this?

Note: For anyone wondering why I need this, I have a collection of strings that when joined together make up a large body of text. Think of the zeroes as the pieces of text and think of the ones as advertisements I am adding in between the text. I wanted to distribute these ads as evenly as possible. I figured this would be a simple way of expressing what I needed.

Comment: How would you distribute 3 ones if the array has 9 or 10 elements?

Comment: The idea is for the array to distribute the ones as evenly as possible. I can't expect it to have an equal amount of zeros between each one and the ends, so something like this would suffice for 10 elements: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]. And for 9 elements: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this.

```
var arr: [Int] =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let distribution = arr.count / 3 // 3 is the number of 1s
for (index, value) in arr.enumerated() {
    arr[index] = (index + 1) % distribution == 0 ? 1 : value
}

print(arr) // [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Assuming that the value distribution > 1

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you!